# Validation Error: when creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set "[object with reference: Product Template - product.template] "

Tags: validation, product, odoo-10

I want to create product category but have validation error

Here is my **.py** code:

```py
class product_product(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    product_package_item_ids = fields.One2many("product.package.item", "parent_product_id", "Product Package Item")


class product_template(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    pack = fields.Boolean(
        'Pack?',
        help='Product Pack?',
        )
    product_package_item_ids = fields.One2many("product.package.item", "parent_product_id", "Product Package Item")
```

Here is my **xml** code:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_template_only_form_view">
        <field name="name">product.template.pack.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="type" position="after">
                <field name="pack"/>
            </field>
            <notebook position="inside">
                <page string="Pack" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('product_variant_count', '&gt;', 1), ('pack', '=', False)]}">
                    <field name="product_package_item_ids">
                        <tree editable="bottom">
                            <field name="product_categ_id"/>
                            <field name="quantity"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="nan_product_pack_form">
        <field name="name">product.product.pack.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="type" position="after">
                <field name="pack"/>
            </field>
            <notebook position="inside">
                <page string="Pack" attrs="{'invisible':[('pack', '=', False)]}">
                <!-- <page string="Pack" attrs="{'required': [('pack','=', True)]}"> -->
                    <field name="product_package_item_ids">
                    <!-- <field name="product_package_item_ids" attrs="{'required': [('attribute_value_ids','=', True)]}"> -->
                    <!-- <field name="product_package_item_ids" attrs="{'required':[('pack', '=', 'attribute_value_ids')]}"> -->
                        <tree editable="bottom">
                            <field name="product_categ_id"/>
                            <field name="quantity"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </field>
    </record>
```

This is error

`The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set`

[object with reference: Product Template - product.template]

How to fix it? any ideas?

Comment: Check the log some lines above the error, that message always have more information there. And by the way, you are creating the same field (`product_package_item_ids`) twice for `product.product` model: take into account that `product.product` inherits from `product.template` by delegation, which means that every field that you create in `product.template` model is automatically generated in `product.product` too.

Comment: Yes, because I want to create boolean pack (product_package_item_ids) on product.product and product.template form , but I only input value pack in product.product form.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to create a `product_package_item_ids` in both `product.template` and `product.product`. Because `product.product` inherits `product.template` model. Remove `product_package_item_ids` from `product.product` model. And try again.